# Swift circular corners doesn't work properly on different screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to achieve smooth round corners on imageviews. Although it's working well on non-plus devices, i can not reach my goal at plus screen devices. Incidentally, i recognize, it's not even work well on the devices that font size enlarged. I applied following code that can be found every topic.

```
    mergedImage.image = lastImage
    mergedImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
    mergedImage.layer.cornerRadius = mergedImage.frame.size.height / 2
    mergedImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

And it's results like pictures below.

[image: At iPhone 8 Plus]

[image: At iPhone X]

[image: At iPhone 5S]

Comment: How is the black shape sized? Does it use Auto Layout?

Comment: @fphilipe yes it is.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the black shape changes size. This can happen when using AutoLayout for example. If that is the case, you need to calculate the corner radius each time the frame changes.

I think the best way to do this is by subclassing UIView to create a "black shape view", and then overriding its `layoutSubviews` method:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
}
```

If you don't have a subclass, you can for example do this in `UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  mergedImage.layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
}
```

Comment: I'll try it, thanks. I will inform you about the results here.